# How to pass argument in this demo of vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to pass argument in this demo of vuejs?
https://jsfiddle.net/u6gvw6xd/3/

error：

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
```

The error is in this line of js code:

```
setSelectedItem(item.message)
```

What should I do？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable names can't have a period `.` in them, see JavaScript variable naming conventions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variables

All you have to do is change the name of the argument variable in your function. It does not have to match the name from your HTML view:

```
setSelectedItem(passedInArgument) {
  this.selected = passedInArgument;
}
```

`passedInArgument` will be evaluated to whatever `item.message` was in your view.

Answer (score 1):

You pass an argument to a function in the form of 'item.message' but in the same function read passed argument ex like this:

```
setSelectedItem(item){
  this.selected = item;
}
```